# ZMQ: Sync messages between APs

Tags: c, network-programming, zeromq

Multiple Access Points are in a network. They need to sync client data whenever a client connects to any one of the AP.

I've studied ZeroMQ [documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) for REQ/REP, PUB/SUB and PUSH/PULL patterns. Not quite sure which pattern really works for the above requirement between PUSH/PULL and PUB/SUB.

In the documentation, it is mentioned that,

> One socket may have many outgoing and many incoming connections.

How to achieve this using one of the above patterns so that the data among APs always in sync.

**Points to be considered**

- APs join network arbitrarily.
- If a client connects to an AP, it's data need to be stored in all APs.
- ZeroMQs are for C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the Harmony peer/peer pattern; it's discussed in the ZMQ guide. Access points could then send a client state message to all their peer access points every time a client connects. No single access point would be a "master" - they would be true peers.

Alternatively you could have one of the access points setting itself up as a "master" (a bound PULL socket), to which slave access points connect and send client data through a PUSH socket. The "master" would then send that data back out to the other access points on a PUB socket, with slave access points receiving that on a SUB socket. It's not a very elegant solution, the master has to handle the entire network's client data traffic, but it may be easier to use.

Comment: Seems like the answer to it. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck, let us know how it went.